# Set up pfSense on AWS VPC?

Tags: firewall, amazon-web-services, nat, pfsense, amazon-vpc

I am attempting to setup pfSense as a nat box for internal servers on a VPC.

I have followed the guides posted for [configuring access](http://www.netgate.com/doc/AWS-VPN-appliance/AWS_VPC_Wizard_user_guide.html#) and have followed the [AWS instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/2781451301784570) for setting up and configuring a nat instance but seem to still be missing something.

Here is a diagram to help convey what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I think where I'm getting stuck is access to the second interface because I can ping the WAN interface but can't ping the secondary NIC I created. Both of the interfaces live in the "public" vpc subnet.

I'm not sure what to look at to get unstuck.

On the pfSense box I have the following outbound nat rule:

[image]

The alias contains the subnet that I am attempting to nat.

Maybe there is a way to configure the WAN interface to be the interface to NAT through and just not even bother with a secondary NIC?  Let me know what other details are needed and I will update.

Comment: From where are you trying to ping the internal interface?

Comment: @EEAA I was attempting to ping from one of the servers I have in the "private subnet".  I had to create a rule to allow LAN traffic in pfSense.  Still sorting out how to get the nat working but ping works now at least.

Comment: Have you added outbound NAT rules for all of your VPC subnets?

Comment: @EEAA You are talking on pfSense right?  I have a catch all NAT rule right now, I will add a picture to the original post.

Comment: @EEAA got it sorted.  I needed to add a LAN rule for web traffic.

Comment: you must deactivate Source/Destinaton check on interface eth1. rega